# Is it possible to have Pandas, Numpy and SciPy work in Xcode?

Tags: python, ios, pandas, xcode, scipy

I have made an app using Python and Kivy and I am trying to get it across to Xcode and eventually iOS devices. It uses Numpy, Pandas and SciPy.... Nothing too special. I am stuck trying to get these into the build across to Xcode and it is very frustrating. I am getting 'No Module' errors in Xcode when running the build.

I have been searching for ages now and can't find any answers....

Surely with how popular Numpy, Pandas and SciPy are there is a way to do this without having to re write the program in Swift with different libraries.

Has anyone had the same issues and overcome it? Is there a way?? Please help.

Can anyone help with this? I’m still stuck

Comment: Have you been able to get ANY Python application to execute on iOS?  That's the hard part.  If you have that hurdle solved, then the rest is just figuring out which Python installation needs the modules.  Numpy and SciPy both have sections written in C (and Fortran) that will need to be compiled for the iPhone processor; that will also be a large hurdle.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Tim Roberts, I have a couple of applications written in python and then transferred across using Kivy-ios (the UI has been kivy). kivy-ios has recipes included for a few things, but nothing for scipy and pandas. How can I go about compiling somwthing like SciPy, I don't know where to start with something like that...